# How to add my public IP address as an inbound rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I have set a VPC that has Cassandra DB nodes, I am trying to add my IP address to some tests, but I can't add my IP address:

Edited the source as:

```
10.0.0.0/16, xx.xxx.xx.xx/0
```

where `xx.xxx.xx.xx` is my public IP address, but I got error:

```
The source must be a valid CIDR (e.g. 0.0.0.0/0) or the ID of another security group.
```

So, how can I add my IP address to the inbounds rules?

Comment: Why are you using /0 for your IP address? Use xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 instead and it will work.

Comment: Yes, its worked with 32 :) can you please tell what does 32 mean?

Comment: Check this link it will give you a idea of CIDR notation.

Comment: Thanks! but I still can't ssh through because t here is no public IP for the EC2 instance, how I would I access the terminal without exposing the IP address to the public? to use internet gateway?

Comment: You will have to create a Bastion host with a public IP address in the VPC which will have access to the EC2 instance you are trying to access.

Comment: I already have a Bastion host, but I could not ssh to it, although I have the key, I tried: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_key root@public.dns.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Don't use root use ec2-user?

Comment: I tried so, I got the same result, as `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: oh, I had to add .pem to the key as: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_key.pem` thank you

Comment: Do you know a working cloudformation template for Cassandra I can start with? I have tried to find one, but I thought you have tried one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your `xx.xxx.xx.xx/0` /0 is not a valid CIDR if you just want to use your IO address use it like this `xx.xxx.xx.xx/32` and it will work.

For reference http://doc.m0n0.ch/quickstartpc/intro-CIDR.html